# API Authenticate... What is that in ANGULARJS? Where is the file?

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I have tried to make login page using http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/angularjs-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

and I ran into a situation you may find silly.

I setup all and now going to try the real authentication, but I have no idea of /api/authentication. I know probably it may look dumb to ask, but I am willing to give a chance to receive advice from professionals how I can implement or download or use that api/authenticate code.
I am using PHP and MY-SQL. I googled, but I found Auth0 site which I don't think that is what I was looking for. The below is the code:

```
/* Use this for real authentication
     ---------------------------------------------- */
    $http.post('/api/authenticate', { username: username, password: password })
        .success(function (response) {
            callback(response);
        });
```

It does not have any .php, or .js extensions, but only the directories. I am a beginner and self-taught for three months to come this far, but I sincerely look for the answers from the experiences of experts rather than just copying and pasting a website to take a look.

Thank you so much for your help in advance! :)

Comment: its called RESP API, google it you will  find documentation about it.

Comment: It is Restful web-service. Search about it on google.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav and Kaustubh! I encountered that but did not fully understand. I will try to give a closer look! Have a good day!